# Ctrl+Z and fg to append commands

Tags: bash, unix

I would like to know what is the behaviour of Ctrl+Z and fg in bash when wanting to append commands to be executed after a running command has finished. For example, in the sequence for commands below, I would expect the console to display "1", then "2", then "3", then "4", but I only get the last command, echo 4, after sleep 30 finishes:

```
avilella@magneto:~$ sleep 30 && echo 1 
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 30
avilella@magneto:~$ fg && sleep 5 && echo 2
sleep 30
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 30
avilella@magneto:~$ fg && sleep 5 && echo 3
sleep 30
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 30
avilella@magneto:~$ fg && sleep 5 && echo 4
sleep 30
4
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the real problem? Are you interested in how ^Z & fg work, or are you trying to script a solution to a specific problem?

Comment: why don't you run `jobs` after every Ctrl-Z and see what you have running

Answer (score 1):

Control-Z suspend a job (not your shell command line), so all the other commands will run without waiting for it. Seems that when you stop a job the shell try to run the next one but as you used `&&` and the previous command was not finished OK (was not finished at all but paused), the command with && is discarded. On the other hand if you use `;` instead `&&` for a second command in the command line, then you would see that the second command gets executed when the first one is paused:

```
$ perl -e '$|=1;for (1..5){ sleep 1;print}print qq{END\n} ';echo test_z00000000000000
12^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 perl -e '$|=1;for (1..5){ sleep 1;print} '
test_z00000000000000
$ fg
perl -e '$|=1;for (1..5){ sleep 1;print} '
345END
$
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not `fg` you want; it might be `wait`. E.g.

```
$ cp large.file some/where
^Z
[1]+ 22224 suspended  cp
$ wait && beep  # beep when first command completes
```

For more info:

```
$ help wait
```

Comment: In what way does `wait` meet the requirement of the OP better than `fg`? 
When I run `./do-work`, hit ctrl-z and type `fg && ./do-other-work`, the output from the first work is again piped to the console and the second work is started when the first one completes. Isn't this what the OP wanted? If I use `wait`, the second work will start without caring about the fate of the first work.